# Referer and Varnish cache conditional code not working

Tags: php, conditional-statements, varnish, referer

I am checking $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] in PHP which is working fine and on the basis of referer value trying to show different slider to the user via if condition, but its not working even condition gets true. I think this is happening due to varnish cache server which is showing always the cached content. Please help how can I achieve the same with varnish server.

Comment: Did you look into $_SERVER["X-Forwarded-For"] ?

Comment: @Julqas Thanks for the reply. I think this is not the issue, issue is the varnish because same is working fine at development server, and headers are also showing the referer response header.

Comment: Sorry I misread, I thought you were talking about $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'] which whas not showing real IP because of Varnish server. My bad..

Answer (score 0):

By default Varnish does not care about the referrer, so will be serving the same cached page to all requests.

If you want a different cache matching rule, then you need to modify the varnish config with extra values in the cache key:

```
# defaults for domain and path will still apply, this is just extra
sub vcl_hash {
    hash_data(req.http.Referrer);
}
```

https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/users-guide/vcl-hashing.html

This will store all the versions as different entries and serve cache matches appropriately.